# Using Navigation stack with 3 wheeled robot

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey so im using a 3 wheeler platform, where the front wheel is used for driving and steering. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to using the ROS Navigation stack with a three wheeled robot; or if its even possible with that style of configuration? I know its mainly used for differential drive platforms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41277/using-navigation-stack-with-3-wheeled-robot/) by [rhettkun](https://answers.ros.org/users/3020/rhettkun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,it seems your vehicle is an non-holonomic model. I am too working on a similar project.

Navigation stack is based  on holonomic and differential drive vehicle. To use it in a ackermann style robot,you need to make lot of changes in the local planner.Plus there is also need to choose the right kind of motion primitives(which is part of sbpl global planner). I would like to know about the hardware configuration of your robot.

Also please have a read:
http://answers.ros.org/question/40447/implementing-slam-on-a-car-like-robot-using-the/

---

Originally posted by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) with karma: 174 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhettkun](https://answers.ros.org/users/3020/rhettkun/) on 2012-08-14**:
ok, so the platform im using is actually a stripped out heathkit hero 1 (I saved it from being totally parted out). it currently has a phenom x4 as the computer, where the sonar eyes were a stripped down kinect fits PERFECTLY, as for the driving mechanism it uses a stepper motor to control the front wheel and a DC motor is the driving motor, which also has an encoder attached to the wheel itself. Im using an arduino 328 chip to communicate with a parallax propeller as the sensing/control mechanism for driving